# Why helpers are registered in 2 different ways in the following example?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

1. Handlebars.registerHelper
2. UI.registerHelper

https://github.com/meteor/localmarket/blob/master/client/helpers.js

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Notice Handlebars instead of Template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these approaches are deprecated.  `UI` was [deprecated](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v091) in version `0.9.1`.  `Handlebars` was  [abandoned](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v080-2014-03-27) in favor of `Spacebars` in `0.8.0`.  From what I can tell, `UI` was a superclass of `handlebars`, before `spacebars` was announced.

Comment: Can you suggest an example app with a public git repo? Thanks.

Comment: The `todo` example is usually the first one when starting Meteor.  https://github.com/meteor/todos

Comment: Though **personal opinion** I am not a huge fan of BlazeJS.  It doesn't have the same adoption as other tools, and thus doesn't have the same number of packages and libraries.  I would suggest taking a look at Meteor React and Meteor Angular 2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

No idea.

You may have already worked out that it doesn't matter. In fact, they are the exact same function. If you compare them in the console you get:

```
> Handlebars.registerHelper === UI.registerHelper
<- true
```

In fact they are all the same:

```
> Template.registerHelper === Blaze.registerHelper && Blaze.registerHelper === UI.registerHelper && UI.registerHelper === Handlebars.registerHelper && Handlebars.registerHelper === Template.registerHelper
<- true
```

(copied from my answer on forums)

Comment: Most interesting.  I suppose thats one way to fix legacy code.